# File_Put_Contents escreve somente metade dos dados

Tags: php, json, array, file-put-contents

Então estou tendo um probleminha com o meu código, a consulta, o for, o foreach e o if funcionam perfeitamente. Contudo o file_put_contents escreve só metade dos dados informados. O meu objetivo com esse código é basicamente, fazer uma consulta do banco, retornar o resultado e em array para ser convertido em json e ser dividido pelo 'montadora_idmontadora' com os modelos de veículos correspondentes a cada montadora. Abaixo o Código que estou tentado fazer :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha Classe:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E por fim a minha Função do Crud:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isso pode está acontecendo pois o `foreach` está passando mais de uma vez com o mesmo contador `$i`. (Como não sei a sua lógica, parece-me isso). Você também pode utilizar dessa forma: `file_put_contents(file, data, FILE_APPEND);` para ele acrescentar, ao invés de substituir o conteúdo.

Comment: Olá @Henrique. Evite colocar imagens do seu código, invés disso edita a sua questão e coloque o código estruturado lá.